# OnTouchEvent is not called before OnItemLongClick

Tags: android, android-listview

In my DynamicListView class, I need to handle two events: onTouchEvent and OnItemLongClick event. My expectation is that the onTouchEvent is called before the OnItemLongClick event. However, this is not the case. The OnItemLongClick event is handled without any call to the OnTouchEvent. Is there anyway to specify the order of these handlers ? I need to get the coordinates of the touch event first before handling the OnItemLongClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` in your `DynamicListView`.

Comment: Can you please more specific ? Thank you.

Comment: @v4r Show your code for setting listeners. Cause i set onTouchEvent and OnItemLongClick listeners and it works fine.